# OOV "frequency"

Tags: mean, frequency, natural-language

I'm writing an algorithm to split twitter hashtags into their component words. I'm splitting the tags into all possible substrings, and then looking up each substring's frequency in a dictionary. I was planning on trying to take the geometric mean of the frequencies, and then compare those values to determine the "best" result.

Since the geometric mean involves multiplication, I need a non-zero "frequency" value for out-of-vocabulary strings. Ideally, this value would be very, but not arbitrarily, small. My naive guess is `1/(# of words in vocabulary)`.